# Wireshark showing multiple Local Area Connections

Tags: wireshark, lan

When I am running Wireshark I can see 4 Local Area Connections on a machine. I don't have physical access to the machine so I cannot check the LAN ports on the machine. Here is the screenshot of wireshark.

[image]

Now when I looking at system properties I am able to see only two LAN connections.

[image]

My questions is, how can I check total number of LAN ports on Windows 7?
Also I can see activity in all LAN Connections together in WireShark, how can I come to know that my packets are going through which connection?

Three out of four connections have identical packet transfer graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you Virtualbox host-only adapter and VMware Virtual Ethernet Atapters are running on local host also.

Comment: Okay, I checked processes and found that vmware is running in background. That explains 4 LAN connections. Can you please tell me how can I find which connection is which in Wireshark?
I also noticed that three out of four connections have identical packet transfer graphs.

Answer (score 6):

You can run `Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden` in **Windows PowerShell** and match up the **Name** property. The **InterfaceDescription** property is what will be displayed in the **Device Manager**.

```
PS C:\Users\glsp168> Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Local Area Connection* 3  WAN Miniport (L2TP)                          16 Disconnected                            0 bps
Local Area Connection* 7  WAN Miniport (IPv6)                          14 Up                                      0 bps
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...       9 Disconnected B8-08-CF-4B-56-56         3 Mbps
Local Area Connection* 10 Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)        7 Not Present                             0 bps
Local Area Connection* 11 WAN Miniport (SSTP)                          22 Disconnected                            0 bps
Local Area Connection* 6  WAN Miniport (IP)                             6 Up                                      0 bps
Local Area Connection* 5  WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)               19 Up                                      0 bps
Wi-Fi                     Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260          15 Up           B8-08-CF-4B-56-52        54 Mbps
Ethernet                  Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM         18 Disconnected 18-DB-F2-30-54-8C          0 bps
Local Area Connection* 1  Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter       17 Not Present                             0 bps
Local Area Connection* 2  WAN Miniport (IKEv2)                          2 Disconnected                            0 bps
Local Area Connection* 9  WAN Miniport (PPTP)                          10 Disconnected                            0 bps
VMware Network Adapte...0 VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for ...       8 Up           00-50-56-C0-00-00       100 Mbps
Zscaler                   Zscaler Network Adapter 1.0.2.0              13 Disconnected 00-FF-72-7E-44-A1       100 Mbps
Ethernet 2                Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Cli...       3 Not Present  00-05-9A-3C-7A-00          0 bps
Local Area Connection* 14 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter           20 Up           00-00-00-00-00...       100 Kbps
Local Area Connection* 8  WAN Miniport (PPPOE)                         23 Disconnected                            0 bps
Local Area Connection* 12 Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter       11 Disconnected B8-08-CF-4B-56-53          0 bps
```

If you want to hide some of them, you can go to **Capture** → **Options**, and then click on the **Manage Interfaces...** button. Uncheck the ones you don't want to see. You can also customize the name displayed if you double click on value the **Comment** column.

[image: Wireshark Manage Interfaces Dialog]